# RegEx for a string to NOT contain two different strings

Tags: regex

Ok you gurus out there who know Regex!

How do you use reg ex to search a string to make sure it doesn't contain either of two different strings.

Example: Say i want to make sure "FileNTile" doesnt contain File or Tile

Thanks

cnorr

Answer (score 12):

```
^((?!File|Tile).)*$
```

This is unlikely to be a good idea though. Almost every programming environment will have a clearer and more efficient approach with string matching. (eg Python: `if 'File' not in s and 'Tile' not in s`)

Also not all regex implementations have lookahead. eg. it's not reliable in JavaScript. And there may be issues with newlines depending on mode (multiline, dotall flags).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language. Easiest way (conceptually): search for both, and make sure both fail to match. In Ruby:

```
s = "FileNTile"
(s !~ /File/) and (s !~ /Tile)  # true if s is free of files and tiles.
```