# How to test if a string doesn't contain BOTH of two given substrings?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to provide a regex that only accepts strings that do not have *both* of the following two substrings: "string1", "string2".  That is, if it has neither string, or if it has only one of them, it should be a match.

Note, this is NOT a duplicate of [regex-for-a-string-to-not-contain-two-different-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158867/regex-for-a-string-to-not-contain-two-different-strings), which asks for regex which rejects strings if *either* of two substrings are found whereas I need a solution that rejects strings only when *both* of two substrings are present.

I've tried:

```
(?!=.*?(string1))(?!=.*?(string2))
^(?!.*(?=string1)(?=string2)).*$
^(?!.*(string1&string2)).*$
^((?!string1&&string2).)*$
```

The correct solution should find matches with (i.e., accept) the following strings:

```
abcd
string1
abcd,string1
string1,abcd
abcd,string2
string2,abcd
```

But should find no matches for (i.e., reject) the following:

```
string1,string2
string2,string1
string1,abcd,string2
string2,abcd,string1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your first two sentences seem to contradict each other.

Comment: @Wiktor This question might very well be a duplicate (I couldn't find one) but the current dup target is not the right one, AFAICT. The other question is regarding matching a string if it contains neither of two words while this one is regarding matching a string if it doesn't contain both words _at the same time_.

Comment: Whoever marked this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158867/regex-for-a-string-to-not-contain-two-different-strings made an error.  That question is asking for something else, and the solution doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Dupe reason corrected, thanks for letting know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?:(?!.*string1)|(?!.*string2)).+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dp12bG/2)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` Start of string.
- `(?:` Start of a non-capturing group.

  - `(?!.*string1)` Ensure that "string1" doesn't exist.
  - `|` OR...
  - `(?!.*string2)` ..that "string2" doesn't exist.
- `)` Close the non-capturing group.
- `.+` Match one or more characters.
- `$` End of the string.

Comment: you solved it @41686d6564!,  Thank you

Comment: @mike_butak You're welcome. I also edited the question to make it clearer as the wording was a little confusing. Feel free to edit it further or fix anything that I might have messed up.

Comment: those edits do make it clearer, thank you.